# Oracle : Insert czech characters from external source

Tags: oracle, unicode

I'm trying to insert czech characters into my database from an external .csv.

If I print the unicode from the word "Sedláček" directly in a worksheet, I obtain "Sedl\00E1\010Dek". But if I print this same word imported from the .csv, I have "Sedl\00C3\00A1\00C4\008Dek" which gives in my database "SedlÃ¡Äek".

Why is this different ? How can I have the right word from the .csv?

This is my code for the import :

```
set serveroutput on;

CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY MYREP as '/foo';

DECLARE
    f utl_file.file_type;
    v_line NVARCHAR2(1000);

BEGIN
f := utl_file.fopen ('MYREP', 'toto.csv', 'R');
    IF utl_file.is_open(f) THEN
      LOOP
          utl_file.get_line(f, v_line, 1000);
          dbms_output.put_line(ASCIISTR(v_line));
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
utl_file.fclose(f);
END;
```

and in my worksheet :

```
set serveroutput on

BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line(ASCIISTR('Sedláček')); 
END;
```

Many thanks for your attention!

Comment: What are your database character and national character sets? If you're reading into an `nvachar2` variable, is there a reason for that, and for you *not* using the `fopen_nchar()` and `get_line_nchar()` variants?

Comment: I didn't know that fopen_nchar() and get_line_nchar() exist ! Now it works, and I feel stupid =D Many, many, many thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation for `UTL_FILE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70899):

> `UTL_FILE` expects that files opened by `UTL_FILE.FOPEN` in text mode
>   are encoded in the database character set. It expects that files
>   opened by `UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR` in text mode are encoded in the UTF8
>   character set. If an opened file is not encoded in the expected
>   character set, the result of an attempt to read the file is
>   indeterminate.

Your use of an `nvarchar2` variable indicates you need to be using the national character set, so you need to use the [`FOPEN_NCHAR` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70922) to open the file, and the [`FOPEN.GET_LINE_NCHAR` procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70932) to read from it.

```
BEGIN
    f := utl_file.fopen_nchar('MYREP', 'toto.csv', 'R');
    IF utl_file.is_open(f) THEN
      LOOP
          utl_file.get_line_nchar(f, v_line, 1000);
          dbms_output.put_line(ASCIISTR(v_line));
      END LOOP;
    END IF;
    utl_file.fclose(f);
END;
```

Comment: @Holyheart - the [`asciistr` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions014.htm) 'returns an ASCII version of the string in the database character set', so this is probably down to your database and national character set differing. You didn't say what those were but only your national char set seems to support Czech fully. If you retrieve the values (as `nvarchar2`) with a client that supports them, do they display properly then? I would expect so, but the client settings will matter. Don't confuse how data is stored with how it's displayed.